# Intersect table with Id scattered

Tags: merge, union, intersection

Help me!
I have two tables (2 file excel. csv) with Id, text, date etc..
I would like to intersect these two tables, within of one, using Id as "landmark". There is a method to avoid to do manually. Considering that the two tables haven't the same rows number.
Therefore, as result I will have one table with all data corrisponding.

So, for example:
1st table: id 1 2 3 4 5, text aaaa bbb ccc                                                 2nd table: 5 1 2, data ......
finally:5 1 2, data...., text aaaa bbb ccc
Maybe with images it is clearer
table 1
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFq7f.png)

table 2
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNASY.png)

Do you have any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Is there a programming language that you would like to do your `intersection` in?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.